# jQuery : Update modal body dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two buttons (Modal 1 & Modal 2) in my web page.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modal 1</button>
      <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modal 2</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>...change string here...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

As can be seen above in the code, both the modals pop up the div "modal-body".

I would like to change the body such that instead "*...change string here...*" it should display the "**id**" of the button that opened the modal.

Can someone let me know if this is possible to do in jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is possible, and it's actually a lot easier than you'd expect!

All you have to do is attach a click handler to both buttons that changes `$(".modal-body > p")`'s **[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**, passing through `this.id` (as `this` refers to the element with the click handler attached):

```js
$("#1, #2").on("click", function() {
  $(".modal-body > p").html(this.id);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modal 1</button>
    <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modal 2</button>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>...change string here...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```